# How do I get the specific amount of words of the value in the child node in xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file in the form of this

```
<parent>
   <child>
      <unique_ID>20210609-6G3TF8P<unique_ID>
   </child>
<parent>
```

I would like to get a new value called ID from the file above, with the value should be 6G3TF8P

How should I do that using XML language?

Answer (score 1):

In the given example, you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(unique_ID, '-')"/>
```

It's not clear from your question if this the logic you want to apply to all your cases.

Comment: The file above is the input file, it will run through a task, which I can get a XML formula to define that task. The task will use the match template and get a value call ID, which takes the words after the - sign of the uniqueID  of the input file.

Comment: Not sure what your point is. Does my suggestion not work for you?